# UIPageViewController: Child Controller ignoring status bar height during scrolling

Tags: ios, statusbar, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having some trouble with a `UIPageViewController`. If I scroll to a new page, the new view controller is **behind** the status bar **while** I'm scrolling. After the scrolling, the view controller position itself **below** the status bar.

I'm using Storyboard (Universal). `UIPageViewController` has attribute `Extend Edges: Under Top Bars`. What am I missing?

[image]

- set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to false didn't work
- use of `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None` didn't work either
- found some open questions here but no answers ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471624/uinavigationcontroller-inside-uipageviewcontroller-with-vertical-scrolling-brok) )

**UPDATE**

Another reason for the jumping are 'Margins' from 'Constraints' ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791183/ios-8-uipageviewcontroller-applying-constraints-after-transitions)). Ensure that you **uncheck** margins if you use constraints (right Dialog). You can remove them later in the Utilities (left Dialog). Check both of the connected views!

[image]

Comment: Just stumbled across the exact same problem and still haven't found an answer :( Please let me know if you get it working

Comment: I can't reproduce it, all pages are behind by status bar regardless of scrolling or not, if I set pageViewController's frame's original Y to 20, all pages are not behind it. A example project will be of some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found a possible solution:

In my case, the `UIPageViewController` container had a `Top Space of 0` constraint to its superview.
The superview was the root container which contains the status bar.

I changed the value of the `Top Space` to 20, which is higher than the status bar. Now it doesn’t move the views below the status bar, because they already are.

Hope that helps!